# DeviceIoControl can't eject a non-empty CDROM drive?

Tags: c#, winapi

I tried using `DeviceIoControl` function (Win32 API function) to eject my CDROM drive, it works perfectly when my CDROM drive has no disk, but after inserting a disk in it, the `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` returned 32 (`ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process), the driveHandle passed in the `DeviceIoControl` is created by `CreateFile()` function.

Could you please help me out? I like this way of manipulating the CD ROM related stuff, I can use winmm.dll to eject my CDROM but I think this way is worth to try.

OK, here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DVD_ejector
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int OPENEXISTING = 3;
        const int IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA = 2967560;
        const uint GENERICREAD = 0x80000000;
        const int INVALID_HANDLE = -1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DriveInfo[] drs = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            List<DriveInfo> cdRoms = new List<DriveInfo>();
            foreach (DriveInfo dInfo in drs)
            {                
                if (dInfo.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom)
                {
                    cdRoms.Add(dInfo);                    
                }                                
            }
            comboBox1.DataSource = cdRoms;               
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

            if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0) comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            button1.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Eject(@"\\.\" + ((DriveInfo)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Name[0]+":");
            };
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string fileName, uint desiredAccess, uint shareMode, IntPtr attributes,uint creationDisposition, uint flagsAndAttribute, IntPtr fileTemplate);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr fileHandle);
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr driveHandle, int ctrlCode, IntPtr inBuffer, int inBufferSize, IntPtr outBuffer, int outBufferSize, ref int bytesReturned, IntPtr overlapped);
        int bytesReturned;
        private void Eject(string cdDrive)
        {
            IntPtr driveHandle = CreateFile(cdDrive, GENERICREAD, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPENEXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            try
            {
                if((int)driveHandle != INVALID_HANDLE) 
                   DeviceIoControl(driveHandle, IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(driveHandle); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it says, something is using it. Try closing whatever has it open (anti virus and explorer are good candidates) and try again.

Comment: If so, why the other ejector application (using winmm.dll) can work well? In fact, the error occured after the call to the CreateFile. The code of ejecting the CD ROM drive I refered from a post in this forum StackOverFlow. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the used code to eject the CDROM Drive, it is verry hard to analyse without it.

Comment: That code doesn't seem to be checking for failure of `DeviceIoControl` (the return value).

Comment: @Deanna: Why do you think that code should be checking for failure of DeviceIoControl? That's just the code to eject the CDROM drive, of course to check for the error, I have to insert a command like MessageBox.Show(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString()) after the line I doubt the error occured at. (The code above only shows the error code and I have to look up for that error code in some Microsoft's site). Thanks!

Comment: @KingKing: As that's the function you say is failing. You should ONLY check the error state (`GetLastWin32Error`) if it says it failed. I can't see any of that going on in the code you've just given.

Comment: @Deanna: In fact, the error couldn't be caught by the try catch block, if I don't use GetLastWin32Error(), I can't know what happened, my application seems to run quietly after clicking the button1, and that's why I tried inserting the method GetLastWin32Error() to see if there was some error, and it returned 32 as I mentioned in my question! I really need a solution to this problem or at least a workaround instead! Thanks!

Comment: You're missing the point. You should ONLY call `GetLastWin32Error` IF the function says it fails with the appropriate return value. If it doesn't "return failure" then the error returned is undefined and can be from something much earlier on. You should check each function call in turn. Oh, and your code works fine here in all cases.

Comment: My code works for you? omg, I can't believe it, but I have to say that, among my Win32 API functions, only the CreateFile has attribute with "SetLastError = true", so if there is some Win32 Error, that will be from CreateFile , and in fact I tried inserting the GetLastWin32Error() method after the CreateFile, even I tried showing the value of driveHandle and it was -1. The error was surely because of the fail of CreateFile. I would like to know why my code works well for you but not for me, in my machine? can it be due to my OS or my CDROM?Thanks!

Comment: I don't need the GetLastWin32Error to know if the CreateFile failed or not, its returned result (which is assigned to driveHandle) is -1 which means that the function couldn't create the File handle (and the Drive handle in this case), or in another words, it failed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, the device is being used by something else, but it's failing on the `CreateFile` call instead of the `DeviceIoControl`, and your code is not correctly checking for the failure.

The reason you're getting a sharing violation is because you're trying to open the device exclusively which will fail if ANYTHING has tried to open it or a file on it, including anti virus, Explorer, Search indexer, etc.

This updated `Eject` function fixes the share mode and the error handling and now reports the errors in the correct places.

```
private void Eject(string cdDrive) {
    IntPtr driveHandle = new IntPtr(INVALID_HANDLE);
    try {
        // Open the device
        driveHandle = CreateFile(cdDrive, GENERICREAD, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, IntPtr.Zero, OPENEXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if ((int)driveHandle == INVALID_HANDLE) { throw new Win32Exception(); }

        // Try and eject
        bool ejected = DeviceIoControl(driveHandle, IOCTL_STORAGE_EJECT_MEDIA, IntPtr.Zero, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (!ejected) { throw new Win32Exception(); }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    } finally {
        if ((int)driveHandle != INVALID_HANDLE) { CloseHandle(driveHandle); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Deanna, it works like a charm. You're so kind to help me out, I wonder where the others were? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry, I just clicked the tick and it turned to green, but I couldn't vote you up, it requires 15 reputation, I'm very new here. Thank you very much, hope you will continue to help me and others.

Comment: Ah, As soon as my reputation is enough, I'll vote up for you! Thanks!